# Help me to interpret my memtest+ result and guide me what to do next

Tags: 14.04, ram, error-handling, diagnostic, memtest

I have previously installed and enjoyed Ubuntu and had both 12.04 and 14.04 but I uninstall both of them and installed 14.04 LTS and it was a disaster for me. Could open my PC anymore due to many reasons so I ran a memtest86+ and found 800+ errors. Here is the screenshot of it

[image]

Comment: No screenshot seen.  Please post a link to an external site with the picture.

Comment: How does one screenshot memtest?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By-qoVNvn34DS05yMjdiX2JoUFE

Comment: here is the screen shot of the image..  before installing this LTS version everything was working fine but when i installed and reinstalled it.. it created a problem for me

Comment: one more thing.. the battery of this laptop is died and i am running it while connecting the power cord.. when power cord is disconnected my laptop turns off.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Your memory module is broken.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*

<sub>(harbinger – Thx [@Fabby](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/132560/fabby) for the nice word)</sub>

---

### Explanation

- **Tst** – shows which test has failed
- **Pass** – Test 4 has one pass
- **Failing Address** – shows exactly which part of the memory has errors.
- **Good** and **Bad** – show the data that was written and what was retrieved respectively. Both columns should be equal in non-faulty memory (obviously).
- **Err-Bits** – shows the position of the exact bits that are failing.
- **Count** – shows the number of consecutive errors with the same address and failing bits.
- **Chan** – shows the channel (if multiple channels are used on the system) which the memory strip is in.

<sub>[Taken from the great answer of BloodPhilia](https://superuser.com/a/326099/427428)</sub>

---

### What is to do?

*I am writing this here for completeness. In your system is only one memory module.*

Use the process of elimination – remove half of the modules and run the test again…

If there are no failures, then you know that these two modules are good, so put them aside and test again.

If there are failures, then cut down to half again (down to one of four memory modules now) then test again.

But, just because one failed a test, don't assume that the other doesn't fail (you could have two failing memory modules) -- where you've detected a failure with two memory modules, test each of those two separately afterwards.

Important note: With features like memory interleaving, and poor memory module socket numbering schemes by some motherboard vendors, it can be difficult to know which module is represented by a given address.

<sub>[Taken from the great answer of Randolf Richardson](https://superuser.com/a/253938/427428)</sub>

Comment: I have a laptop and i dont know how this module thing couod be done.. should i take it to toshiba service centre.. and how much does it cost to repair such things.. is the motherboard is safe ?? One thing i forget to mention is this problem could be aroused due to no maintainance of this laptop from the past 3 years ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a hardware expert.

Comment: @BalramSingh Run the test again with a single module; if it shows no error the module removed is the faulty one, otherwise test the other as well as they might be both broken, and trust me, you don't want bad RAMS, because they break everything.